# linker error with classes in c++

Tags: c++, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

I have created this code

```
  class Game{
    static SDL_Surface* screen;
public:
    //Initiate Game(SDL_Graphics, folder for output.....) 
    static void initialize();
    static void initializeScreen();


};

void Game::initializeScreen()
{

    Game::screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 32,  SDL_DOUBLEBUF |SDL_HWSURFACE |SDL_SWSURFACE);
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    Game::screen == NULL ? printf("SDL_Init failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError()):printf("SDL_Init initialized\n");
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("SDL Animation", "SDL Animation");
}
```

It compiles but I get e linker error, how can I fix this?

```
1>game.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static struct SDL_Surface * Game::screen" (?screen@Game@@0PAUSDL_Surface@@A)
```

**Edit:** This is how I fixed it, in game.cpp 
added this

```
SDL_Surface* Game::screen;
```

outside of any function*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define static (variable) members (not functions) in seperate source files(*.cpp) and link against them.

for example:

```c
//MyClass.h
class MyClass {
    static int x;
};

//MyClass.cpp
#include "MyClass.h"
int MyClass::x;
```

Comment: i get this error `error C2655: 'Game::screen' : definition or redeclaration illegal in current scope`

Comment: thanks for help, I have figured it out, I tried to put it into the function initializeScreen() which didnt work, so I put it outside of the function and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following definition in your cpp file `SDL_Surface* Game::screen = NULL`.

---

Here is an example code where you can have a `static` variable without defining it in the cpp file using a function.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Lazy {
    static int& GetValue() {
        static int a = 0;
        return a;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << Lazy::GetValue() << std::endl;
    int& a = Lazy::GetValue();
    a = 1;
    std::cout << Lazy::GetValue() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: is it not private by default?

Comment: I think your issue is caused because you have not defined `SDL_Surface* screen;` in the cpp file. static variable need to be define like `SDL_Surface* Game::screen = NULL` in you cpp file.

Comment: this does not work as I cant assign value to a funtion

Comment: @arcana has anwsered the question corectly , you just edited it when you seen that your anwser didnt work

Comment: @Laggy No, I edited it because you did not seem to understand **Lazy initialization**.

Comment: you gave me a funtion that returns SDL_Surface screen

Comment: @Laggy I updated the code with an example of what I was speaking about.